# Bash: I am unable to run the eval command inside a double while loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell, expect

My goal is to have a program that loops through two files and evaluates a separate shell script with all combinations of lines from file1 and file2. I verified that my eval line works by moving it out of the while loop.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line1
do 
    while read line2
    do 
        eval "ssh_connect $line1 $line2"
    done < $FILE2
done < $FILE1
```

ssh_connect creates a new ssh connection based on a username and password provided in command line arguments.

```
set username [lindex $argv 0];
set password [lindex $argv 1];
puts "$password"
puts "$username"
spawn ssh $username@<location>.com
expect "assword:"
send "$password\r"
interact
```

I have verified that the above script works properly. However when I call it from inside the sub-shell of the while loop it prompts for a password and doesnt put it in as expected.

How can I modify my first shell script so that it evaluates the second one properly

Comment: Are you sure you need to use `eval`? That's only needed if the files contain shell syntax that need to be interpreted. If the files just contain usernames and passwords, you should be able to do `ssh_connect "$line1" "$line2"`

Comment: Look into using public key authentication rather than writing custom wrappers like this to supply a password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `interact` in the Expect script switches to reading from standard input. Since stdin is redirected to `$FILE2` at that point, it reads everything in that file. When the inner loop repeats, there's nothing left in the file, so the loop terminates.

You need to save the script's original standard input, and redirect `ssh_connect`'s input to that.

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 3<&0 # duplicate stdin on FD 3
while read line1
do 
    while read line2
    do 
        eval "ssh_connect $line1 $line2" <&3
    done < $FILE2
done < $FILE1
```